# axis2 fails to generate java from wsdl with inline schema

Tags: java, xsd, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I want to generate Java classes from a WSDL. I'm invoking wsdl2java from within an ant task. The commandline would look like this:

```
java -cp ... org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java -o generated_dir -S . -R . -l java -p "com.make.me.rich" -d adb -or --noBuildXML -uri MakeMeRich.wsdl
```

The MakeMeRich.wsdl contains inlined schemas from Micrsosoft, e.g.:

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfint">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="int" type="xsd:int" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="ArrayOfint" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfint" />
    <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
          <IsDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</IsDictionary>
        </xsd:appinfo>
      </xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="KeyValueOfstringstring">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Key" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="Value" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring" />
</xsd:schema>
```

But the wsdl2java parser gives a warning:

```
[java] Warning: No schemaLocation for import of http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays; compilation may fail
```

Any ideas how to handle inline schemas with wsdl2java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using databinding `xmlbeans` seems to solve the problem: `-d xmlbeans`.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Axis2 are you using? I'm facing a similiar problem with version 1.6.x while everything works fine with 1.5.x and below. Could you try it with an older version?
In my opinion using xmlbeans is not a solution, it's just a workaround.

Comment: I'm using Axis2 1.6.2. The Axis2 project page states that ADB is "By no means [...] intended to be a fully functional schema compiler like XMLBeans." ([ADB HowTo](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/adb/adb-howto.html)). So I understood that you can't expect any WSDL construct to work with ADB.

Answer (score 0):

make that as inline schema in your wsdl.

Comment: Thanks Ratha for the hint. When I looked closer at the WSDL with your recommendation of inlining the schemas I found that the WSDL actually already used inline schemas. So it seems that wsdl2java isn't handling inline schemas correctly when called like I do.