# Microsoft CRM 2015 SOAP interface introduces new namespace, but I cannot find it in the generated OrganisationServiceStub?

Tags: wsdl, axis, wsdl2java, xrm

We have been using the SOAP interface of Microsoft CRM online succesfully for a few years, but with the introduction of version 7.1 we see in the SOAP response entries like this

```
<b:KeyAttributes xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/7.1/Contracts" />
```

When I inspect the WSDL of the service endpoint, I can see the declaration, however when I want to generate a new OrganisationServiceStub, this namespace is not picked up. This is the command I use

```
D:\Software\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\bin>WSDL2Java -uri https://microsoft.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl -p java2crmpack -s -o D:\XRM\Client
```

The effect on existing code is an error when we invoke (parse the soap reponse) the webservice

```
org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts}KeyAttributes
```

Of course I start isolating this particular namespace and do some manual coding, but I think this should be picked up by the Axis tooling, right ?
I am sure the .java files are generated (I have reserved a brand new folder:-)

Comment: May be it is related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568551/axis2-fails-to-generate-java-from-wsdl-with-inline-schema  the Microsoft WSDL/XSD introduces inline schema entries in this version. Unfortunately axis2 seems to be the only way to get a decent java client for this webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also had this issue as soon as 7.1 was released. I fixed it by re-generating the stub classes. The Microsoft website provides step-by-step instructions on how to do this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979%28v=crm.5%29.aspx . Once I re-generated the stubs and replaced the old ones everything worked fine again. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

when you say 7.1, do you refer to jdk version??

WSDL2Java -uri https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc?wsdl -p java2crmpack -s -o c:\projects\Java2CRMCRUD

WSDL2Java -uri https://yourcrmonlineinstance.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl -p java2crmpack -s -o c:\projects\Java2CRMCRUD

That´s what you mean?

I also delete urn: namespace and nothing, it doesn´t work for me...   :(

Comment: 7.1 is the CRM version